# Is the node module folder shared in a Next js multi zone set up?

Tags: next.js

I'm making a multi-zone Next js app and can't find any info on how to handle the node module folder. Was curious if each zone can share the same node module folder or if it is best to have a node module folder for each zone. I'm making a four zone setup and 2 zones share a lot of the same modules and the other 2 zones do as well. Just wanted to cut down on size of app if I could.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since both are separate applications and only connected via rewrites I strongly suspect that all dependencies are separate for each zone.